# Simple Prototyping in javascript test

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="id1">Click to know</div>

<script>
function Superheroe(power){
    this.power=power;
}
//edited: copy mistake solved
Superheroe.prototype.sayYourPower=function(){
    alert('This is my power :'+ this.power);
}

var Mike = new Superheroe ("Code fast");


document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener("click",Mike.sayYourPower);
</script>
```

I'm wonder why I'm getting 'undefined' when I ask for the sayYourPower...It is for not including the "()" at the end of the method?

Comment: you add function to `Person` prototype, but create object from `Superheroe`. and also even if you change `Person` to `Superheroe` it would not work, because in your case `this` inside event handler refers not to object `Superheroe`

Comment: I make a mistake sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your Superhero object is yet to extend the Person prototype, hence Mike doesn't have a function `sayYourPower`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be

```
<div id="id1">Click to know</div>

<script>
  function Superheroe(power){
    this.power = power;
  }

  Superheroe.prototype.sayYourPower=function(){
   alert('This is my power :'+ this.power);
  }

  var Mike = new Superheroe("Code fast");
  document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener("click",Mike.sayYourPower.bind(Mike));
</script>
```

Comment: you call `sayYourPower` before adding handler, so to onclick would be attach result this function - _undefined_

Comment: Did you test this? Also, what do you think the OP was trying to do with the "Person" class and how does your answer address that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Superheroe` instead of `Person`, and also use `bind` function, or anonymous function as handler, for savinf context

```js
function Superheroe(power){
    this.power=power;
}

Superheroe.prototype.sayYourPower=function(){
    alert('This is my power :'+ this.power);
}

var Mike = new Superheroe ("Code fast");


document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener("click",Mike.sayYourPower.bind(Mike));
//another variant with anonymous function
//document.getElementById('id1').addEventListener("click",function(){Mike.sayYourPower()});
```

```html
<div id="id1">Click to know</div>
```